# Solr edismax is not returning results as expected. Trying to use qf for weight indexing

Tags: solr, edismax

I have a search that queries to the Solr data. And it works mostly correct. However the result is not sorted the way I'd expect it to. There is; name, description and id and I'd like a way to make the ID more important in the search. Now, an exact match of ID does not put the result on top of the results. Which is what should happen. Even if another result has the same queried string in its name field.

qf, didn't help because when I add it, only exact matches return.
Any help is appreciated

Below objects when searched for: 123456
Should return [C, B, A], because say ID matters more

```json
A: {
 id: 678678,
 name: 'some name',
 desc: '123456',
},
B: {
 id: 456456,
 name: '123456',
 desc: 'some desc',
},
C: {
 id: 123456,
 name: 'some name',
 desc: 'some desc',
},
```

Lastly we do have;
defType=edismax and some other fields

adding **qf** to the parameters
qf=id^10 name^7 desc^5

was tried like so, without any luck

Comment: What is the type of your `id` field? Did you try appending `&debug=all` to you query and look at the explanation for the scoring? Since `id` is a unique field, it might not contribute as much to the score as you think.

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm new to Solr was hoping to understand the content search axis. Thanks, a lot for the answer!